# C++: Unable to use the object name which passes struct and enum as parameters

Tags: c++, class

I have a class constructor which accepts string, struct, enum and int as parameters. Apart from this I also have a default constructor. 
Whenever I call my class functions using the object name that's created using the parametered constructor, I'm getting some error saying member is of non-class type. But I don't get any error if I use the default constructors object name.

```
Car obj(string bini, struct Date dini, enum Status state, int id);
obj.getBrand();  //doesn't work. getting non-class type error

Car obj1;  //constructor without parameters
obj1.getBrand(); //works fine
```

here's the more detailed code.

```
//main.cpp
struct Date
{
int year = 0;
int month = 0;
int day = 0;
};
enum Status{ OK, SOLD, DEFECT };
int main()
{
string bini = "";
int id = 0;
Car obj(string bini, struct Date dini, enum Status state, int id);
obj.getBrand();  //doesn't work. getting non-class type error
//  Car obj1;  //constructor without parameters
//obj1.getBrand(); //works fine
}
//Car.h
class Car
{
public:
struct TDate
{
int year;
int month;
int day;
};

enum TStatus{ OK, SOLD, DEFECT };


void getID();
void getPrice();
void getBrand();
TStatus getStatus();
TDate getManufactureDate();
void setPrice(float price);
void setStatus(TStatus state);
void sellCar();
Car();
Car(string bini, struct TDate dini, enum TStatus sini, int id);
protected:
private:
TStatus state[100];
string brand[100];
float priceEuro[100];
int carId[100], bc = 0, pc = 0, dc = 0, sc = 0;
TDate manufatureDate[100];
};
//Car.cpp
Car::Car(string bini, struct TDate dini, enum TStatus sini, int id)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
brand[i] = {bini};
manufatureDate[i].day = dini.day;
manufatureDate[i].month = dini.month;
manufatureDate[i].year = dini.year;
state[i] = sini;
carId[i] = id;
}
} 
void Car::getBrand()
{
cout << "Enter the Brand of the Car : " << endl;
cin >> brand[bc];
carId[bc] = bc;
bc++;
}
```

I don't get the mistake I'm doing here. Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `Car obj(string bini, struct Date dini, enum Status state, int id);` is a function declaration. Search for "vexing parse" and you'll get tons of answers. And I think you wanted to write `Car obj(bini, dini, state, id);` in the first place.

Comment: Car here's my class name and obj is my object name. And you are right, I want to pass paramaters as you say, i have just added data types in front of them.

Comment: Remove them as @jrok suggested and it should be back to normal :)

Comment: @jrok: This doesn't look like most vexing parse to me. `Car obj1();` would have been.

Comment: The most most vexing parse would be `Car obj1(Car());`, I think :) You're correct, though, it isn't actually ambiguous. Still, the answers will be in vexing-parse tag, I suppose.

Comment: @jrok: I tried with your suggestion, but now it says dini, state are declared in the scope. So i'm getting error in the Car obj(..) line itslef

Comment: Show us some code with context and exact error message, it's hard to guess what the real problem is.

Comment: error: 'dini' was not declared in this scope|

Comment: @all: Posted more details of my code. Kindly help me out

Comment: there are a pleny of mistakes in your code. my advice would be to brush up all your concepts once again.

Answer (score 2):

```
Car obj(string bini, struct Date dini, enum Status state, int id);
```

That's a function declaration. Leave out the types of the variables you pass.

```
Car obj(bini, dini, state, id);
```

Comment: Yeah, I tried this. Now I'm getting error in the first line itself. It says 'dini' and 'state' were not declared in the scope

Comment: @Kay: You need a `Date` and a `Status` in order to use that constructor. If you have them (but with different names) then change the constructor arguments to match their names; otherwise, create them.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: posted more details about my code, please help me out!

Comment: @Kay: Then declare `dini`! I think it's best to suggest you to grab a C++ book. There's plenty of information about good books here.

Comment: @phresnel: I have been reading a lot about this issue, but i dont find where i'm doing the mistake. Even after declaring dini and state in separate lines, i'm getting this error: request for member 'getBrand' in 'obj1', which is of non-class type 'Car(std::string, Date, Status, int) {aka Car(std::basic_string<char>, Date, Status, int)}'|

Comment: @Kay: It sounds like you still have the declaration you posted in the question (containing type names so that it declares a function), not the object declaration this answer told you to change it to. I suggest you carry on working through your book to learn exactly how declarations work.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found what the mistake is. The struct and enum of Car.cpp should be defined globally. And then its variable declaration should be done in main.cpp as it's done below.

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
string bini = "";
int id = 0;
TDate dini;    //previously i was using separate temporary struct and enum 
dini.day = 0;  //inside main, that was not necessary. Now since the class Car's
dini.month = 0;  //struct and enum are global i can use them here to declare variables
dini.year = 0;   //for enum, i directly passed the value OK thru constructor
int id = 0;
Car obj1(bini, dini, OK, id);
obj1.getBrand();  //no error now
}
//Car.h

struct TDate    //**global definition**
{
int year;
int month;
int day;
};

enum TStatus{ OK, SOLD, DEFECT };
class Car
{
public:
void getBrand();
Car();
Car(string bini, TDate dini,TStatus sini, int id);
private:
TStatus state[100];
string brand[100];
float priceEuro[100];
int carId[100], bc = 0, pc = 0, dc = 0, sc = 0;
TDate manufatureDate[100];
};
//Car.cpp
Car::Car(string bini, TDate dini, TStatus sini, int id)
{
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
brand[i] = {bini};
manufatureDate[i].day = dini.day;
manufatureDate[i].month = dini.month;
manufatureDate[i].year = dini.year;
state[i] = sini;
carId[i] = id;
}
} 
void Car::getBrand()
{
cout << "Enter the Brand of the Car : " << endl;
cin >> brand[bc];
carId[bc] = bc;
bc++;
}
```

Thanks.